# Best practice to handle non-english characters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

My program file is encoded in UTF-8 so `"abc".length == 3` but `"åäö".length == 6`. I realize that å, ä, ö, etc. are stored as two bytes in UTF-8, and that a Ruby String is a sequence of bytes (not characters), but it is annoying! Is there a best practice to work around this problem?

Comment: You still can ruby 1.8 with $KCODE = 'u' ; require 'jcode' ;  a"åäö".jlength #=> 3

Comment: Thanks, your comment is very valuable to everyone who has not upgraded to 1.9. (After upgrading I have also learnt that I could have submitted a switch (-e or so) when invoking the ruby interpreter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ruby1.9

```
$ ruby1.8 -e 'puts "åäö".length'
6
$ ruby1.9 -e 'puts "åäö".length'
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this command on the top of your file:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks but I still get "åäö".length==6